# Is this best practice for having my divs setup?

Tags: html, css

I wanted the 1st div to have a picture on the left and text on the right. On the 2nd div, I want text on the left and a picture on the right.

Is my css best practice for doing this?

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/g8mbgr1e/13/

Here's my code:

```
    <div class="wrapper-20-80">
    <div class="left-20-80">
    <p><img alt="Pear" src="http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/pear/pear-01.jpg" width="144" height="150" /></p>
</div>
    <div class="right-20-80">
<p>
   The pear is native to coastal and mildly temperate regions of the Old World, from western Europe and north Africa east right across Asia. It is a medium-sized tree, reaching 10–17 metres (33–56 ft) tall, often with a tall, narrow crown; a few species are shrubby. The fruit is composed of the receptacle or upper end of the flower-stalk (the so-called calyx tube) greatly dilated. Enclosed within its cellular flesh is the true fruit: five cartilaginous carpels, known colloquially as the "core". From the upper rim of the receptacle are given off the five sepals[vague], the five petals, and the very numerous stamens.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper-20-80">
    <div class="left-80-20">
        <p>
   In ancient Egypt, artists used an orange mineral pigment called realgar for tomb paintings, as well as other uses. It was also used later by Medieval artists for the colouring of manuscripts. Pigments were also made in ancient times from a mineral known as orpiment. Orpiment was an important item of trade in the Roman Empire and was used as a medicine in China although it contains arsenic and is highly toxic. It was also used as a fly poison and to poison arrows.</p>
</div>
    <div class="right-80-20">
    <p><img alt="Orange" src="http://wallwallhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/orange-slice-wide-wallpaper.jpg" width="144" height="150" /></p>
    </div>
</div>

Here's my CSS:

    .wrapper-20-80 {

    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

    .left-20-80 {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
    }

    .right-20-80 {
        width: 80%;
        float: right;
    }

    .left-80-20 {
        width: 80%;
        float: left;
    }

    .right-80-20 {
        width: 20%;
        float: right;
    }
```

Comment: So you want the Pictures of the fruits under the description or above?

Comment: I'm not seeing any issues in your fiddle. The Orange pic is below the Pear to the right and the Pineapple is below the Orange to the left.

Comment: Yes, so it looks more like a table would look.

Comment: Answer: no, this is not best practice. You are putting decisions about your presentation in your markup, and you are naming classes for how things *look* rather than what those things *are*.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2fay9p0b/

Basically I surrounded each picture and it's corresponding text with a div that clears the float on both sides:

```
.clear{
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: I like what you did in your fiddle - your answer would be better if you included more of those details here and explained how/why it works. I might do 2 things differently... I see this as presenting a list of items, so I'd use `<ul><li><div>(image)</div><div>text</div></li>...` as the structure, then use the `nth-child` selector to alternate the floats, rather than putting that presentation decision in the markup as div classes.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Stephen. Can you show how you would do it with a jsfiddle?

Comment: @user3075987 See http://jsfiddle.net/2fay9p0b/1/

Answer (score 0):

Markup (your HTML) should represent *structure*, not *presentation*.

Your content is a list of things; each thing listed consists of an image and a text description, so your basic structure should be:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>(image)</div>
        <div>(text)</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Classes on elements (and used in CSS) should be named to distinguish *what* something is, not how you want it to look. Filling out the above to better specify what these parts are could result in:

```
<ul class="entries">
    <li>
        <div class="itemimage">(image)</div>
        <div class="itemtext">(text)</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now you decide you want the images to alternate left and right. That is a *presentation* decision and should be handled in CSS. In the real world you may occasionally need to add extra markup, but you should avoid that if possible.

In this case it **is** possible to style it without extra markup.

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul li {
    clear: both;
}
ul li:nth-of-type(2n+1) div.itemimage {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 30px 20px 0px;
}
ul li:nth-of-type(2n) div.itemimage {
    float: right;
    margin: 0px 0px 20px 30px;
}
```

This first removes the list bullets, then makes sure each list-item starts a new block (because we're using floats)

It next styles odd (2n+1) and even (2n) list items differently — floating the image in one left and the other right.  The margins may not be necessary with the images actually present, or you may want them anyway.

See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fay9p0b/1/) for a demonstration.

Comment: I strongly disagree, but because it is opinion based and not invalid markup I won't -1 you. I generally think lists should never be used to summarise sections of content. For instance, you wouldn't output a blogroll as a list. It is better to have consecutive articles or sections. For instance, in this case I would use articles as a wrapper.

Comment: @BramVanroy I certainly agree about a blogroll, and maybe these are each articles, and maybe they would be better as a `<div>` instead of an `<li>`, but there's not enough context in the OPs question for me to know that. In any case, the *technique* here works with either divs or lists enclosing the content, and the *principals* I espouse hold true and "you" (the OP or the plural you) have to choose the appropriate kind of container.

Comment: I agree, even though it does seem that he is trying to write different sections about different fruits, so in my answer I used articles. [Check it out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25434222/1150683)! We better wait on some comments of other peeps, so we can see who thinks what exactly.

Comment: Wow, easy to follow explanation. One thing those, I didn't see css for one of your classes: itemtext

Comment: @user3075987 There is no CSS for the itemtext class because none was needed for this example; but in real-life you might want the class there anyway in case you want to change its style later, or manipulate it with javascript. That doesn't mean throw a class on *everything*, that would be overkill, but judicious use of classes where you don't yet *require* them can make future re-styling easier.

Answer (score 0):

My approach combines user145400 and Stephen P's answers. I disagree with Stephen that the representation should be semantically reflected in a list, and I made a small adjustment to user145400's *clearfix*. I also thought he used too many divs and wrapping elements.

What you do is, simply use HTML 5's `article`. It speaks for itself, actually. Every fruit gets its own little space, with a wrapping `article` element (that self clears its children), a thumbnail, a nice heading (I highly recommend this, mainly for SEO purposes) and the text itself.

It would look like this:

```
<article>
  <img src="" alt="">
  <h2>Bananas</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</article>
```

This way, you can write very specifically and individually about each item, without an overload of divs. Nice and simple is key.

In the fiddle I added some classes because it is possible that you have other images and articles on your web page. By adding these classes, you can easily identify the elements. Stephen P is right in saying that you should name them to what they are rather than what they look like. It makes life so much easier because you immediately know what "fruit-image" refers to.

You can find the final fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2fay9p0b/3/). Example article:

```
<article class="clear fruit-entry">
  <img alt="Pear" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/61/Alexander_Lucas_10.10.10.jpg" class="fruit-image">
  <h2>Pear</h2>
  <p>The pear is native to coastal and mildly temperate regions of the Old World, from western Europe and north Africa east right across Asia. It is a medium-sized tree, reaching 10–17 metres (33–56 ft) tall, often with a tall, narrow crown; a few species are shrubby. The fruit is composed of the receptacle or upper end of the flower-stalk (the so-called calyx tube) greatly dilated. Enclosed within its cellular flesh is the true fruit: five cartilaginous carpels, known colloquially as the "core". From the upper rim of the receptacle are given off the five sepals[vague], the five petals, and the very numerous stamens.</p>
</article>
```

Important CSS:

```
article.fruit-entry:nth-child(2n) > img.fruit-image {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 1em 1em;
}
article.fruit-entry:nth-child(2n+1) > img.fruit-image {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
}
/* Clearfix as per http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/ */
.clear:after {
    content:"";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You said in your comment that you wanted it to be like a table? Why not actually make it a table. Something like this maybe?

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><img alt="Pear" src="http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/pear/pear-01.jpg" width="144" height="150" /></td>
            <td><img alt="Orange" src="http://wallwallhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/orange-slice-wide-wallpaper.jpg" width="144" height="150" /></td>
            <td><img alt="Pineapple" src="http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/pineapple/pineapple-02.jpg" width="144" height="150" /></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td>The pear is native to coastal and mildly temperate regions of the Old World, from western Europe and north Africa east right across Asia. It is a medium-sized tree, reaching 10–17 metres (33–56 ft) tall, often with a tall, narrow crown; a few species are shrubby. The fruit is composed of the receptacle or upper end of the flower-stalk (the so-called calyx tube) greatly dilated. Enclosed within its cellular flesh is the true fruit: five cartilaginous carpels, known colloquially as the "core". From the upper rim of the receptacle are given off the five sepals[vague], the five petals, and the very numerous stamens.</td>
            <td>In ancient Egypt, artists used an orange mineral pigment called realgar for tomb paintings, as well as other uses. It was also used later by Medieval artists for the colouring of manuscripts. Pigments were also made in ancient times from a mineral known as orpiment. Orpiment was an important item of trade in the Roman Empire and was used as a medicine in China although it contains arsenic and is highly toxic. It was also used as a fly poison and to poison arrows. Because of its yellow-orange colour, it was also a favourite with alchemists searching for a way to make gold, both in China and the West.</td>
            <td>The pineapple is a herbaceous perennial which grows to 1.0 to 1.5 meters (3.3 to 4.9 ft) tall, although sometimes it can be taller. In appearance, the plant itself has a short, stocky stem with tough, waxy leaves. When creating its fruit, it usually produces up to 200 flowers, although some large-fruited cultivars can exceed this. Once it flowers, the individual fruits of the flowers join together to create what is commonly referred to as a pineapple. After the first fruit is produced, side shoots (called 'suckers' by commercial growers) are produced in the leaf axils of the main stem. These may be removed for propagation, or left to produce additional fruits on the original plant.[4] Commercially, suckers that appear around the base are cultivated. It has 30 or more long, narrow, fleshy, trough-shaped leaves with sharp spines along the margins that are 30 to 100 centimeters (1.0 to 3.3 ft) long, surrounding a thick stem. In the first year of growth, the axis lengthens and thickens, bearing numerous leaves in close spirals. After 12 to 20 months, the stem grows into a spike-like inflorescence up to 15 cm (6 in) long with over 100 spirally arranged, trimerous flowers, each subtended by a bract. Flower colors vary, depending on variety, from lavender, through light purple to red.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ugh! Tables are for tabular data — **don't** use tables for layout... it is a worst practice.